# ConTeXt SciTE tries to open sumatrapdf by default

Tags: pdf, installing, context, viewers

I just installed SciTE and ConTeXt on windows using the directions from this website http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Windows_Installation:_ConTeXt_Suite_with_SciTe

And it appears everything works but for one issue. When I press Ctrl+F12 to compile the tex file into a pdf, it complains because I don't have sumatrapdf installed. But I do have adobe's pdf viewer installed. I installed sumatrapdf and it launches sumatrapdf.

I would like to get it to launch Adobe's pdf reader. Any idea how to go about doing this?

Comment: The reader configuration can be found in the file `l-pdfview.lua`, particularly interesting here is the `pdfview.method` entry which is set to `sumatra`. Try `context --autopdf=acrobat file`.

Comment: @Marco Would you like to write up an answer?